# use xyf() function in Kohonen package to do some prediction in R code

Tags: r, neural-network

## I met some problems when using xyf() and predict.kohonen() in R

> As follow is a sample copy from documentation of package kohonen, version 2.0.19. You can see it at https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/kohonen/versions/2.0.19/topics/xyf
>
> However I've tried it and met some problems.
>
> 1.When I use xyf(),Error in factor(wine.classes[training]) : object'wine.classes' not found
>
> 2.Then when tried predict(),object 'xyf.wines' not found
>
> 3.I changed xyf() to
>       xyf.wines <- xyf(Xtraining, vintages[training], grid = somgrid(5, 5, "hexagonal")) it works and I get the xyf.wines
>
> 4.But when I tried to predict,I failed again. Rstudio said Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
>     Data type not allowed: should be a matrix or a factor
>   5.Since step 4 failed, I could not use table()

```
library(kohonen)
data(wines)
set.seed(7)
wine.classes<-vintages
training <- sample(nrow(wines), 120)
Xtraining <- scale(wines[training,])
Xtest <- scale(wines[-training,],center = attr(Xtraining, "scaled:center"),
           scale = attr(Xtraining, "scaled:scale"))
xyf.wines <- xyf(Xtraining,factor(wine.classes[training]),
             grid = somgrid(5, 5, "hexagonal"))
xyf.prediction <- predict(xyf.wines, newdata=Xtest)
table(wine.classes[-training], xyf.prediction$prediction)
```

Comment: When I try to reproduce your code I receive the error: `Error: object 'wine.classes' not found`, could you define this object in your example?

Comment: using: `predict(xyf.wines, newdata = as.data.frame(Xtest))` should work.

Comment: predict(xyf.wines, newdata = as.data.frame(Xtest)) doesn't work                  
Error in check.data(newdata) : 
  Argument data should be a list of numeric vectors or matrices, or factors

Answer (score 0):

```
library(kohonen)
data(wines)
set.seed(7)
#wine.classes<-vintages
training <- sample(nrow(wines), 120)
Xtraining <- scale(wines[training,])
Xtest <- scale(wines[-training,],center = attr(Xtraining, "scaled:center"),
               scale = attr(Xtraining, "scaled:scale"))
Xtraining_data <- list(measurements = Xtraining,
                       vintages = vintages[training])
Xtest_data <- list(measurements = Xtest,
                   vintages = vintages[-training])
xyf.wines <- xyf(Xtraining,vintages[training],
             grid = somgrid(5, 5, "hexagonal"))
xyf.prediction <- predict(xyf.wines, newdata=Xtest_data)
table(vintages[-training], xyf.prediction$predictions[[2]])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).